# Module name has not been loaded yet for context using RequireJS text plugin

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using [text.js](https://github.com/requirejs/text) to load templates and I'm getting an error on

```
require('text!templates/categories.html')
```

the error is

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "text!templates/categories.html_unnormalized2" has not been loaded yet for context:
```

Have a look at my view section in the require loading process of the template that's where the error is thrown.

Project directory structure:

```
js
    /app
        ....
        views/categories
        templates/categories
    /lib
        /jquery
        /underscore
        /backbone
        /text
    /vendor
        /jquery-ui
        /fancytree
```

RequireJS configs:

```
require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module

    shim: {

        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            exports: "$",
            deps: ['jquery']
        },  
        'fancytree': {
            deps: ['jquery-ui']
        }, 

    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone': '../lib/backbone/backbone',     
        'text': '../lib/text/text',
        'jquery-ui': '../vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui',
        'fancytree': [      
            '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree',
            '../vendor/fancytree/fancytree.table'
        ],      
    },

    baseUrl: '/js/app',

});
```

view:

```
define(['jquery-ui', 'fancytree', 'require'], function(ui, fancytree, require){

    'use strict';

    var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),  
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        tpl = require('text!templates/categories.html') /* this line here produces error loading text.js*/,
        template = _.template(tpl);


    return Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#tree'),
        initialize: function() {

            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset add change remove', this.render, this );
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        initFancyTree: function() {
            console.log('tree');
            $('#fancytree').fancytree();

        },
        render: function() {

            console.log(this.collection.toJSON())
            this.$el.html(template());
            //this.initFancyTree();
            return this;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c)

Comment: Please take the time to read the documentation and to debug your code before asking. [It's not been 15 minutes from the moment you had the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712506/error-loading-jquery-ui-in-require-js-config-for-fancytree-plugin#comment68653176_40712532) and the moment you posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to require modules using CommonJS syntax which [RequireJS tries to emulate](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#commonjscompat) by loading the template asynchronously.

Since it's not ready yet when you try to use it, it throws the error.

You'd only need the following to get it to work:

```
define([
    'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'jquery-ui', 'fancytree',
    'text!templates/categories.html'
], function(
    $, _, Backbone, ui, fancytree, 
    tpl
) {
    'use strict';
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#tree'),
        template: _.template(tpl), // can be put here directly
        initialize: function() {
            // only has 3 parameters
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset add change remove', this.render);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        }
    });

});
```

Additional information (and similar questions):

- [Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448839/1218980)
- [Module name has not been loaded yet for context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36143342/1218980)
- [Error: Module name "xxx" has not been loaded yet for context](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/615)